# How to remove Windows 10 digital licence

Tags: windows-10, windows-activation

I want to activate Windows with a product key by doing a clean install.Is it possible to get rid of digital entitlement on a system

Comment: You can still activate your machine with a product key, it's just not necessary, since your digital entitlement is linked to your product to begin with. What problem are you trying to solve exactly?

Comment: Slmgr does not fetches the product key but the same old licence

Comment: I don't understand that comment.  I have no idea what commands you are running.  Just saying `Slmgr` fetches the product key doesn't tell me anything.

Comment: 'Slmgr/ dli' does not fetch the partial product key I used

Comment: What exactly is it you are trying to achieve? This feels like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: You can simply change the key as per the duplicate.